# ajax does not want to work

Tags: php, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reportPost(args, id) {
var reason = prompt("Reason");
  if (reason == null || reason == "") {
    return false;
}
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "testajax.php",
data: "reason=" + reason + "&" + args,
success: function(msg) {
    var reportSpan = document.getElementById('report' + id);
        reportSpan.parentNode.removeChild(reportSpan);
}
});
}
</script>

<span id="report<?php echo $pid ?>"><a href="#" onclick="reportPost('post_id=<?php echo $pid ?>', <?php echo $pid ?>);return false;" rel="nofollow"><img src="exclamation.png"   alt="Report" /></a></span>
```

All I have in ajax.php is:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reports (message) VALUES ('test')");
```

Nothing gets inserted to that table and i am connected trust me

Comment: should "testajax.php" be "/testajax.php"?

Comment: The usual recipe: ff & firebug, enable NET, see the request and/or javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you said all you have in "ajax.php" is that command, but your script is targeting testajax.php.

Comment: And although is it called ajax.php, you maybe should open a db connection first, parse your parameters, etc, etc.